# msfconsole exiting when run within detached 'screen'

Tags: linux, display, gnu-screen, metasploit

I'm trying to figure out why `msfconsole` is exiting when started from with a detached screen, but not when started from a non detached screen.

Here are the steps:

```
screen -d -m -S msf
screen -S msf -p 0 -X stuff "msfconsole\n"
screen -R -S msf
```

`msfconsole` exits right after loading where:

```
screen -S msf
msfconsole  <-from within screen
```

allows it to actually run without exiting after loading. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that helped me .

A simple approach is to: ssh in to your metasploit box, run screen -dRR, and in the resulting shell run msfconsole. Then, in the future, if you disconnect your ssh client and reconnect, just run screen -dRR again and you'll be connected back w/your screen session running msfconsole. The screen -dRR command also creates a screen session if one does not exist, which is why it works even when there is no existing screen session.

just open an other ssh session or terminal  then run screen -d  or just screen -d if running a single screen.

Regards

Comment: Perhaps I’m misunderstanding, but it seems to me that this is at best a workaround.  If this is an actual solution, please explain how it answers the question. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Yes that's a work around... I need it to start in detached mode and run that command.